# Java 8 - Check if Double is within range?

Tags: java

I know that for Integers, Java 8 has IntStream which allows you to generate ranges and check them, e.g.

```
IntStream range = IntStream.rangeClosed(5,10);
range.anyMatch(x -> x == 4);
```

My problem is that I have Double ranges, defined as:

```
Light     [0, 3.0)
Moderate  [3.0, 6.0)
Vigorous  >= 6.0
```

The variable being checked against these ranges is a `double val`. I was just wondering if Java 8 has any convenient solutions for this. I don't want to use elaborate `if/else` trees for various reasons.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(5,10)` returns a stream containing (only) the integers `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. What do you expect a stream "range" of `Double` to return? Surely you don't want _every possible Double_ between your endpoints?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good use of what you're calling "ranges".  `IntStream` is really just exactly that - a stream of integer values.  `anyMatch` is checking *every single value* in that range against the provided predicate.  It's not clear what that would mean for floating-point values.

Comment: [Guava's Range class](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) might be a fit if you don't already know about it. It's not exactly a new Java 8 solution, though.

Comment: what's so bad about `Range getRange(double x){
        if(x >= 0 && x < 3)
            return Range.LIGHT;
        if(x >= 3 && x < 6)
            return Range.MODERATE;
        return Range.VIGOROUS;
    }` ? assuming you have a `Range` enum with the aforementioned constants.

Comment: Aomine - I'm repeating numbers in every if/else; if I add new categories it's not the cleanest code to maintain; it would be more elegant with a range solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pkpnd stated in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960809/java-8-check-if-double-is-within-range#comment86938088_49960809), there is a known difference between one `int` and the next (ex. `4` and `5` are one integer apart).  However, how far apart are two arbitrary `double`s, an ulp?

One suggestion that I have to emulate a *range* is to use a `NavigableMap`:

```
enum Range {
    LIGHT, MODERATE, VIGOROUS, UNKNOWN
}

NavigableMap<Double, Range> map = new TreeMap<>();

map.put(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Range.UNKNOWN);
map.put(0D, Range.LIGHT);
map.put(3D, Range.MODERATE);
map.put(6D, Range.VIGOROUS);

System.out.println(map.floorEntry(4D).getValue());
```

Output:

```
MODERATE
```

You're free to handle out-of-range values however you'd like, as well a `Double.NaN`.